# PrettyFaces and h:link outcome tag don't redirect to a clean URL

Tags: jsf-2, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

My rewriting with PrettyFaces for an error page doesn't work for a h:link and I don't understand why.

My link should redirect to `login.xhtml` and it should be `/Login`.

What is happening, do I miss something?

My rewrite rules navigation :

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/pageNotFound.xhtml</from-view-id> 
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

My web.xml for error page handling and Pretty Filter configuration:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pageNotFound.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

My pretty-config.xml:

```
    <url-mapping id="login">
    <pattern value="/Login" />
    <view-id value="/login.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

My pageNotFound.xhtml:

```
<rich:panel style="width:50%;margin-top:100px;" header="Page Not Found.">
    <h:link value="Login page" outcome="login" />
</rich:panel>
```

Comment: If you use h:commandLink with action="login", it's working...but i'd like why it's not working with outcome and h:link...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you're mixing Prettyfaces' view id with JSF's one. You can't directly use this id in JSF context, you [need to tell](http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/navigation.html#navigation.commands) it that it's a *pretty* id. This should work:

```
<h:link value="Login page" outcome="pretty:login" />
```

Also if you prefer to use JSF id, you could use */login* directly instead:

```
<h:link value="Login page" outcome="/login" />
```

Prettyfaces' filter should take into account that it's a mapped id and redirect to your */Login* url directly.

Comment: Already test that, and i get the same issue with the second and with your first solution it sends me back a strange like, something like ocpsoft.mapping_id=login... I decided to use command link instead. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: What a strange behaviour, are you reaching Prettyfaces' filter when doing that?

Comment: you mean my Pretty Config Filter? i post the config below. Weird behavior,i'm agree :) , it should work as you mentioned , it's why i don't understand what is not well configured.

Comment: Your filter seems to be properly configured. I tell you just to put a breakpoint at `com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter` class and debug it. And, by the way, it's better to edit your own question including updates in order to publish an answer with that.

Comment: Xtreme Biker is correct; you can't mix JSF navigation rules with PrettyFaces Mappings. You have to use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't mix JSF navigation rules with PrettyFaces Mappings. You have to use one or the other.

```
<rich:panel style="width:50%;margin-top:100px;" header="Page Not Found.">
    <h:link value="Login page" outcome="login" />
</rich:panel>
```

I believe that "login" should instead be "/login", otherwise JSF may not resolve it. I could be wrong.

```
<rich:panel style="width:50%;margin-top:100px;" header="Page Not Found.">
    <h:link value="Login page" outcome="/login" />
</rich:panel>
```